# Pipe netcat response to php post form

Tags: linux, bash, php, curl, netcat

I'm trying to get a one-line command that pipes all messages on a port to a php script. I can't use a netcat proxy, as the receiving end is webserver-only.

Basically, I have the idea of doing something like this:

```
nc -d localhost 30003 | curl -d @- https://URL/file.php
```

How would I actually do this? Such that all messages from the nc connection are sent to the php script. **On a per message basis (Curl request for every line of nc received)** Preferably without waiting for the curl to finish, to allow for large amounts of messages to continuously send.

Comment: Are you trying to perform a single massive POST with all data, or multiple (e.g. one POST per received line)?

Comment: @grawity Updated